# Adaptive Delayed Chained Payment in Paypal- Partial Refund

Tags: c#, paypal, asp-classic, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are using Adaptive Delayed Chained Payment method to transfer funds from one party to another party with ourselves as an intermediary merchant that takes a percentage. In this scenario we are the primary receiver and there is a secondary receiver as well. In case of a partial refund to the party sending the money (the client) we need to transfer the balance fee less our commission to the secondary receiver.

It seems that we cannot call the "Execute" function after the partial refund process to complete the transaction flow. i.e. once the the client is partially refunded, we as the intermediary and primary receiver hold the balance funds. The secondary receiver does not get paid since we cannot call the "Execute" function. So the balance fee is stuck at the primary receiver end. So how can we send the balance fee to the secondary receiver in this partial refunding process? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Two of us have searched this site and other sites, but cannot find anywhere that addresses this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please show some relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You could either switch and send the partial refund via another method such as send money tab in your account or Implicit Payments API..  OR you could utilize Implicit payments to send the money from your account to the secondary receiver.  Keep in mind by doing that you will be having a separate transaction to the secondary which won't tie to the previous paykey and will be subject to any applicable transaction fees. Another option would be to wait on any refunds until after the completion of the Delayed Chained Payment.